# die() or echo not working

Tags: php, mysqli

when add die() before `mysqli_query` it is working, but it is not working after  `mysqli_query`
the same code was working when i'm using `mysql_query`

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="jilphar";
$con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

 //die("here"); working here
$rslt           = mysqli_query($con,"select width,height from image_size where imageName='Admin Logo'");
$row            = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt);
$imageHeight    = $row["height"];
$imageWidth     = $row["width"];
die("here"); // here not working
```

connection is working fine

Comment: I presume you are removing the first `die()` to get the second to work?

Comment: first die is not there in my code, i just added for testing, it is working, but second not

Comment: you've killed the connection so i doubt it'ld run the second part of your code mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die ("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());

Comment: Instead of die() in the last bit of our code, you can awel just close connection

Comment: your code working for me

Comment: try usinng this error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); to find out errors

Comment: May I ask what is your output when you use only second die? Is your script continuing? What if you add `echo` after it? Maybe some error occurs before this `die()`

Comment: die() not working, and following scripts continue, i tried echo also but not working

Comment: If there is not working even `echo` it seems like before this action occurs some error which is terminating your script.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove firs die I think he will work :-)

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer, do you not think?

Comment: @Blinkydamo, right but his reputation is less than 50 so he cant comment

Answer (score -1):

There are many things that could go wrong.

If you are receiving a "blank" response from server(`Response code: 200`).

It could mean that, the script encountered an error and the error was suppressed, due to a setting inside php.ini or during runtime.

If no response is received then it means that the query is taking more time than expected and you are thinking that the execution has stopped.

I mean It could be just that the query is taking lot of time to execute and you are thinking that the `die` is not working.

Comment: but scripts after die() continue

Comment: When you say `die()` and `echo()` both arent working how are you determining that the execution is proceeding?